# Access websites connection string from web jobs

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I have been trying to move my connection strings from the App.config files for my webjobs to the host website through the Azure Portal. I've tried the likes of:

```
ConnectionStringSettings test = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureDB"];
```

I've also tried using GetSetting and putting the connectionstring in the app section of the configure options as a key/value pair.

That still only shows my local connection strings. I've also tried using the CloudConfigurationManager to no avail.

There are examples all over the place and in SO citing:

> However, you don't have to set it in app.config for the web job if you set them in the portal. The WebJobs SDK knows how to read them from there.

So how do I access them?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager)
2. Move your connection strings to the appSetting section (for debug purpose)
3. Retrieve you connection string using the `CloudConfigurationManager`:

   ```
   var myConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MyConnectionString");
   ```
4. You can now manage your connection string from within the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

Azure WebJobs shares the settings with your website

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/16/configuring-azure-web-jobs/